# ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException in multi dimentional array

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am getting the following Exception in thread "main" : `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 2 error:`

My code:

```
int ia=445;
int ja=445;

double [][][]ma=new double [445][445][2];
ma=na;
for (int kk=1;kk<=2;kk++)
{
   int jj=2;
   if (kk == 2)
   {
     jj=ja;
   }
   for (int ii=2;ii<ia-1;ii++)
   { 
    double uu=0.5*abs(ma[ii][jj][2]+ma[ii-1][jj][2]);
    System.out.println(uu);

   }
}
```

Though there are no **ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException** issues, I am still getting this exception. Can some one explain how to fix this issue?

Comment: You should format your code better - helps improve legibility. Also, arrays are 0-index based, not 1-index based.

Comment: `there are no ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException issues, still i am getting this exception` This confuses me.

Comment: you have declared ja and initialized with 445 but you never use that variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ma[ii-1][jj][2]` will give you an exception regardless of the values of `ii` and `jj`, since the last index must be either 0 or 1 (since the dimentions are `[445][445][2]`).

Answer (score 1):

The problem is here:

```
double uu=0.5*abs(ma[ii][jj][2]+ma[ii-1][jj][2]);
                             ^               ^
                             here            here too
```

You can only access to indexes `0` and `1` in the third *dimension* of your array.

Maybe you want/need:

```
double uu=0.5*abs(ma[ii][jj][1]+ma[ii-1][jj][1]);
```

or

```
double uu=0.5*abs(ma[ii][jj][0]+ma[ii-1][jj][0]);
```